# Overload operator>> to read data from stream

Tags: c++, struct, stream, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the operator>> to read data for Comp c, from a stream (.txt file). Everything is read correctly except the first number, "difficulty". It's always displayed as 0.

Here's the struct for Comp:

```
struct Comp
{
    string name;
    double points[7];
    double difficulty;
};
```

And this is the function to overload>> (It should ignore the extra ws in the .txt file):

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Comp& c)
    {
        getline(in, c.name);
        in >> ws >> c.difficulty >> ws >> c.points[0] >> ws >> c.points[1] >> ws >> c.points[2] >> c.points[3] >> ws >> c.points[4] >> ws >> c.points[5] >> ws >> c.points[6] >> ws >> c.points[7] >> ws;
        cout << c.name << endl;
        cout << c.difficulty << endl;

        return in;
    }
```

Here's the function in which the overload>> function is used:

```
int read_competitors(istream& in, Comp V[], int n)
{
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter < n && (in >> V[counter])) {
        ++counter;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

And finally this is what the .txt file looks like:

```
Anna Lindberg
2.3 6.8 7.2 6.4 8.1 2.5 6.2 7.0 
Test Name
2.3 3.4 5.6 7.8 8.5 5.4 3.6 4.7
   First Last
2.2 7.8 7.5 8.7 7.2 9.2 7.5 4.5 
Asdf Tyui
1.9 7.8 5.6 3.4 3.8 5.1 5.9 7.2
Jio Wkfjf
2.4 4.0 4.2 5.1 4.3 7.7 4.9
```

Why isn't the first number read correctly (!0)?

Please let me know if I've missed any other useful information.

Comment: `c.points[7]` is out of range

Comment: @DieterLücking I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Comp::points array can hold only 7 elements, so accessing  `c.points[7]` is invalid (out of range).